# Name of distribution that is the square root of the sum of the squares of normal distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Imagine a dart board. You throw a dart, and you have two normally distributed variables, $X$ and $Y$, representing the distance in the x and y direction from the bullseye. Obviously then, the radius $R = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$. What is the name for the distribution of $R$?

As far as I can tell, it's a Rayleigh distribution, but I don't know enough to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is Rayleigh distribution, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) states so explicitly in the **Related Distributions** section.